# extend parent class from a child class that was called inside

Tags: php

I have this code below that simply load a class from a separate php file that should extends the parent class `Loader`

parent class

```
namespace Loader;

class Loader{
    public function load($name){

        $module_name = ucfirst($name);
        require_once(__DIR__.'/'.$module_name.'.php');

        return new $module_name;
    }
    public function parentFunction(){
       return get_class($this);
    }
}

$loader = new Loader;
```

Captcha.php

```
namespace Loader;

class Captcha extends Loader{
    public function callParentFunction(){
        var_dump($this->parentFunction());
    }
}
```

then call the captcha from Loader via test.php

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/Loader.php');

$loader->load('captcha')->callParentFunction();
```

it throws me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Loader' not found

pointing this line

```
class Captcha extends Loader{
```

any help, suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a namespace or `use ...` declaration in `Captcha.php`? If not, you'll need it.

Comment: `class Captcha extends Loader` seems rather ridiculous to begin with, if you ask me. A captcha _is_ not a “loader”, so it should not extend that class in the first place.

Comment: @Aaron it throws class 'Loader\Loader\Loader' not found

Comment: @Yoshi just did, it throws me "class 'Loader\Loader\Loader' not found"

Comment: @04FS loader should be the parent class that should be extended by all the child classes that was called from calling '$loader->load'

Comment: Weird, the error is more likely to be `class Loader\Loader`.

Comment: @iArcadia I have updated the code, this line, $loader->load('captcha')->callParentFunction(); is on separate file called test.php

Comment: Have you `include`d the .php file in which `class Loader` is defined anywhere? Are you using an autoloader?

Comment: @deceze see the code above, I have required it from the test.php, not using php autoloader at all.

Comment: solved it, it should be namespace Loader on the Captcha.php but now when I initiate the class using new $module_name; it returns Fatal error: Class 'Captcha' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error means that you have some other `class Captcha` probably in some other file which does *not use a namespace*, and that gets loaded. Somewhere you're jumbling up two different implementations of this class.

The problem is that your captcha class is not called `Captcha`, it's called `Loader\Captcha`. Since you're instantiating it from a string, that string needs to contain the *fully qualified name* of the class. Currently your code is looking for a class called `Captcha`, not `Loader\Captcha`.

Either do `$loader->load('Loader\Captcha')` and sort out the namespace internally somehow, or add the namespace internally:

```
$module_name = ucfirst($name);
$class = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $module_name;
require_once __DIR__ . '/' . $module_name . '.php';
return new $class;
```

Again, this does not solve your issues with what's in what file though, since I can't see your files.

Comment: solved it, it should be namespace Loader on the Captcha.php but now when I initiate the class using new $module_name; it returns Fatal error: Class 'Captcha' not found